# Why can't we add properties to a function object inside function body like we do for object literals in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Look at the code below

```js
var foo = function(){
    prop1 : "value";
}

foo.prop2 = "value";

console.log("prop1" in foo)    // logs flase
console.log("prop2" in foo)    // logs true
```

Why can't we add properties to a function object like we do in an object literal? Why had I to declare the property for the function object outside its body? Is there a different syntax to add properties to a function object directly in its body.

Comment: ignoring the syntax errors, you never call/instantiate foo() to define `prop1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the grammar of functions in javascript doesn't allow for it. What you need is just a plain object.

> Is there a different syntax to add properties to a function object
>   directly in its body.

Yes. There is. And it's called a constructor function.

```
function Foo(){
    this.prop1 = "value";
}
var obj = new Foo();
console.log(obj.prop1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using something akin to CoffeeScript? You forgot the `{}` on the object.

First I suggest you return a proper object:

```
var foo = function(){
    { prop1 : "value" };
}
```

Still it won't work. It will result in:

```
foo.prop2 = "value2";
{ [Function] prop2: 'value2' }
```

`foo()` will return

```
{ prop1: 'value' }
```

`foo.prop2` will return `value2`

The reason it doesn't work is because you're adding to the instance. Not to the function body (You can't change the code, just the objects.).

A better solution would be:

```
var newFoo = foo()
{ prop1: 'value' }
newFoo.prop2 = "value2";
{ prop1: 'value', prop2: 'value2' }
```

As we've seen, you CAN modify the function, but you can't modify it's return statement, because it would require the software rewriting the function and we're not quite skynet... Yet. ;D

Another interesting way of modifying stuff is prototyping:

```
Function.prototype.prop2 = "value2"
foo()
{ prop1: 'value' }
foo.prop2
'value2'
```

But seeing as `Function.prototype` will make EVERY FUNCTION gain the `.prop2` property, it wouldn't make much sense in this case.

Answer (score -3):

Because you have used a semi colon. You do it using a comma.

Correct usage would be:

```
var foo = {
    prop1 : "value",
    prop2 : "value"
}
```

Comment: This will require `foo` to be invoked at least once

Comment: what? really? It should result in `Unexpected token :`

Comment: I understand the need for speed: But you should really have a workable version before you post anything.